# XSLT transform using TXMLDocument

Tags: xml, delphi, xslt, msxml, xmldom

I was trying to use TXMLDocument for XSLT transforming and found unexplained (for me) behavior - TXMLDocument.transformNode does't process the '/' pattern (matched with root node https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256113(v=vs.85).aspx).

XML:

```
<notelist>
  <note>NoteText</note>
</notelist>
```

Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"  indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <TransformedNoteList>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>  
    </TransformedNoteList>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" /> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using TXMLDocument Delphi code:

```
var
  XML: IXMLDocument;
  XSL: IXMLDocument;
  Output: XmlDomString;
begin
  ResultMemo.Clear;

  XML := LoadXMLData(XMLMemo.Text);
  XSL := LoadXMLData(XsltMemo.Text);

  XML.DocumentElement.TransformNode(XSL.DocumentElement, Output);

  ResultMemo.Text := Output;
```

I expected some thing like this as result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TransformedNoteList></TransformedNoteList>
```

but got empty xml file.

I tried to reproduce this behavior via using IXslProcessor and all works fine.
Can somebody explain me what is using TXMLDocument for transforming because as is understood in not working via IXslProccessor?

Using IXSLProcessor:

```
var
  XMLDoc, XSLStylesheet: IXMLDOMDocument;
  XSLProcessor: IXSLProcessor;
  XSLTemplate: IXSLTemplate;
begin
  ResultMemo.Clear;

  XMLDoc := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
  XMLDoc.LoadXML(XMLMemo.Text);

  XSLStylesheet := CoDOMDocument60.Create;
  XSLStylesheet.LoadXML(XsltMemo.Text);

  XSLTemplate := CoXSLTemplate60.Create;
  XSLTemplate._Set_stylesheet(XSLStylesheet);
  XSLProcessor := XSLTemplate.createprocessor;
  XSLProcessor.Input := XMLDoc;

  if XSLProcessor.Transform then
    ResultMemo.Text := XSLProcessor.Output;
end;
```

And what is the correct solution for XSLT transformation?

Comment: I don't know the API you use but `XML.DocumentElement.TransformNode(XSL.DocumentElement, Output)` seems like an explict attempt to start the transformation with the root element (e.g. `notelist` in your sample) and not the document node `/` and in that case your stylesheet indeed doesn't output anything. So if the API you use allows you to call `TransformNode` directly on `XML` I would suggest to try that respectively find another way to run the transformation on the document node and not on the root element.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin says, `match="/"` matches the top node in the tree (DOM and XPath 2.0 call this a document node, XPath 1.0 calls it a root node). But you have started the transformation by supplying the outermost element in the tree (DOM calls this the document element). To match the outermost element you need the pattern `match="/*"`.

Comment: Thanks Michael,

I found this information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms757005(v=vs.85).aspx

For correct transforming via TXMLDocument need to use XMLDocument.Node... not XMLDocument.DocumentElement.